# Linq Where condition to match array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have a linq list obtained from database in my Model. Now I have a string array obtained from my controller. I want to construct a statement

pseudo-code

```
List<object> objlist = db.objects.tolist();
string[] strarray; // obtained from a long code.
var k = objlist.Where(u => u.somecol == strarray[0] || u.somecol == strarray[1]........strarray[n]).toList();
```

I am little bit confused how to accomplish this since my `strarray[]` is variable length and can contain upto 1000 words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check if an array contains some item using the [Array.IndexOf<T> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx):

```
bool strarrayContainsX = Array.IndexOf<string>(strarray, "X") >= 0;
```

However, I'd recommend you use a [HashSet<string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of a string array for anything more than a few items. [The HashSet<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) provides a [Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) to check if a set contains some item:

```
HashSet<string> strset = new HashSet<string>(strarray);
bool strsetContainsX = strset.Contains("X");
```

The resulting query then looks like this:

```
var k = objlist.Where(u => strset.Contains(u.somecol)).ToList();
```

Comment: If you use generic `IndexOf` method, you may leave out the `<string>` type argument as it can be inferred. If you use Linq extension, there is also `strarray.Contains("X")`. But of course `HashSet` performs better for large collections.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Contains`:

```
var k = objlist.Where(u => strarray.Contains(u.somecol)).toList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
List<object> objlist = db.objects.tolist();
string[] strarray; // obtained from a long code.
var k = objlist.Where(u => strarray.Contains(u.somecol)).toList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var k = objlist.Where(u => strarray.Any(x=>x == u.somecol)).ToList();
```

Comment: Linq has the `.Any` extension method, but Linq also has a `.Contains` extension method, and with that you can get rid of the inner-most lambda.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, that's right however I'm familiar with this and after submitting, I recognized that there had already had some other answers using `Contains`, so I let it unchanged.